# Run several Applescripts from within current script

Tags: applescript

I'd like to expand my existing...

```
run script file "Macintosh HD:Users:pathTo:myScript.scpt"
```

to run all scripts found in a given directory. I've tried...

```
tell application "Finder" to set scriptsToRun to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/pathTo/" as alias list
    run script file scriptsToRun
```

but no luck with that. Also unless necessary I don't particularly need to involve Finder in my equation. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scriptsToRun is a list, so you need to repeat over the list and run each one separately. Notice I used parenthesis to ensure the code is interpreted correctly in the Finder line.

Also notice you don't need "file" in the "run script" line because the list of files is already a list of alias files... from the Finder line. You would only need the word "file" if you had a list of files in string format, then you'd use "file" before each string to make it a file specifier before running it.

Good luck.

```
tell application "Finder" to set scriptsToRun to (files of folder POSIX file "/Users/pathTo/") as alias list

repeat with aScript in scriptsToRun
    run script aScript
end repeat
```